# Como usar o reduce() em um map() com dados vindo do Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, map, firestore

Tenho um array de dados vindo do firestore. Com os dados recebidos pelo firestore eu faço um `map` para disponibilizar a visualização como uma tabela. Quando eu tento fazer um `reduce` para calcular a soma de todos os valores, retorna que o `reduce` não é uma `function`.

Segue os dados vindo do firestore:

```
{data: 1/1, desc: 'conta de gás', price: 138}
```

Meu map:

```
{viewContas && viewContas.map(vc => {
                        if(auth === vc.authorId)
                            return (
                                <tr key={vc.id}>
                                    <td>{vc.data}</td>
                                    <td>{vc.desc}</td>
                                    <td>R${vc.price}</td>
                                    <td>
```

Não consigo usar `{vc.price.reduce(~~)}`.

Answer (score 0):

Opa amigo tranquilo?

Então, creio que você esta tentando usar o metodo `reduce()` em um valor único, utilizando ele dentro do seu map.

Para conseguir utilizar o `reduce()` você tem que utilizar em uma lista, segue o exemplo a baixo.

```js
let data = [
  {data: 1/1, desc: 'conta de gás', price: 138},
  {data: 1/1, desc: 'conta de gás', price: 139},
  {data: 1/1, desc: 'conta de gás', price: 140},
]

let prices = data.map( (v,i) => {
  return v.price;    
})

console.log( prices.reduce( (a,b) => {
  return a+b;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Não consegui amigo, continua o mesmo erro... Lembrando que o `viewContas`, é por onde estou acessando o firestore pelo redux `viewContas: state.firestore.ordered.contas`

```
const { viewContas, auth } = this.props

        let prices = viewContas && viewContas.map((v,i)=>{
            return v.price;
        })

        console.log( prices.reduce( (a,b) => {
            return a+b;
          }))
```

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined**